# Color code cells based on demographics and test scores (multiple conditions)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have established a datasheet with all 4th grade students.  This data includes name, race, economically challenged, and their latest state assessment scores.

Column D is race - N if White / Y if other than White
Column E is economic situation of child - if in trouble Y / otherwise N
Column G is their test score.

Here is what I cannot get to work...

If any student scores less than a 70, we need the text to be RED (which I can do easily).

However, I need to figure out a way to recognize this...
If D is = Y, AND the grade is less than 70... I need to fill the cell with red and have white text.  Any student that is D = N and still less than 70... text should remain red.

That is one problem.  I need a separate rule to recognize when D = Y and E = Y AND score is less than 70... I need to fill that cell with black.

Our goal is to recognize quickly the deficiencies in our non-White and very low income students.

Is there anyone who may be able to help?

Comment: What cell format gets changed? Column G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional formatting.

Under conditional formating go to Manage Rules.  You are going to add three rules.  In the end it will look like this:

[image]

The formulas are:

```
=AND($D2 = "Y",$E2 = "Y",$G2 <70)
=AND($D2 = "Y",$G2 <70)
=$G2 <70
```

Add the three rules with the corresponding formats.  **Then make sure they are in the order that is shown in the picture**.  Also make sure that the "Applies to" cover the entire needed range.

Comment: My school computer will not let me access the image.  I will try this now to see if I can possibly figure it out. :)

Comment: @BWhite the main thing to ensure is that the order goes from the most variables to the least.  So the one with three is on top and the one with one on the bottom.

Comment: I have typed the formulas exactly as shown above.  However, the result was not correct.  I must be missing some element. Are blanks needed between $D2 and the "Y"?  Grasping for answers.

Comment: @BWhite Which excel are you using?

Comment: @BWhite Just to be sure there are three different formula for three different rules.  could you paste one of the formulas exactly as you typed them in?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010.   I actually wrote out what I need with an adjustment.     $D2="Y",$e2="Y",$g2<70) - Red fill    $D2="N",$e2="Y",$g2<70) - Orange Fill     $D2="Y",$e2="N",$g2<70) - Yellow Fill, and then lastly  $D2="N",$e2="N",$g2<70) - red text    Do you believe that this is how it should be completed?

Comment: I believe that the above is working.  However, I am not able to not format if the cell is blank.  It is formatting all cells even when a test score has not been inputted.  Suggestions?  I so much appreciate your help!!!  I know that our admin, parents, and students also appreciate your help.

Comment: @BWhite so the formulas should be in this format `=And($D2="Y",$E2="Y",$g2<70)`  Change the Y and N to what you want but you are in the right track.  So you will have four of these formulas.

Comment: @BWhite Change the formula to this format `=And($D2="Y",$E2="Y",$g2<70,$g2>0)`

Comment: Can you tell me what adding $g2>0 does in the calculation when you get a free minute?